# Why does Gson deserialize 1 to 1.0?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.fromJson("1", Object.class));    //output:1.0
System.out.println(gson.fromJson("1", String.class));    //output:1
System.out.println(gson.fromJson("1", Integer.class));   //output:1
```

I'm trying to custom a deserializer to fix it,but still not work:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Object.class,new JsonDeserializer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,JsonDeserializationContext context)throws JsonParseException {
        return json.getAsInt();
    }
}).create();
System.out.println(gson.fromJson("1", Object.class));   //still 1.0
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Gson are you using? The latest versions are more permissive about letting you override type adapters for core types.

Comment: This seriously is a big flaw in GSON.

Comment: I agree. If there is no decimal point then why suddenly add one. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong here?

You're doing something you most probably don't need. Moreover, it's really wrong, as it breaks for everything but numbers.

IIRC, Gson deserializers for some build-in types (including `Object`) don't work.

Whenever you use something like `List<Integer>`, the json will be read as int, so everything's fine.

There might be some cases where you use `Something<Object>` and want to get `Integer` rather than `Double` there in, however I doubt if such a code makes sense. In case it does, write a deserializer for `Something` and fix the problem there.

Answer (score 4):

There are no integers in JSON. 1.0 and 1 are the same thing, except 1.0 is explicit.

Comment: Yes, I understand,Is there a way I can get 1 instead of 1.0?

Comment: Well, given that JSON doesn't know what an integer is ... it hardly seems likely.

Comment: @Zenofo I'd be more concerned about the code on the other end that needs to have a "1" instead of a "1.0"

Answer (score 2):

If your destination class has int members, it'll deserialize into ints.  Otherwise, just cast it to (int) if you're using fromJson w/o parameters.

Comment: It helped me. I was converting Object to MyPojo class, From webservices i was fetching e.g success 1 . and my pojo was getting into String. I changed to int. I got my desire values. thanks,.